# How to figure out which character failed the Regex match in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have following code which fails the validation if special characters are found in the file name:

```
 var validationResult = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_ ]+$/.test(fileName);
```

This works great and returns the correct results. However, now my customer wants to know  which character actually failed the validation. How can I change the code so that I can point to the character which failed the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Change `RegExp.prototype.test()` method approach with `String.prototype.match()` method:

```
var validationResult = fileName.match(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_ ]/g);
```

If `validationResult` is not `null` it's an array containing all matched special characters

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question, which is to explicitly find which characters *don't* match this regex

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to store the acceptable group regex, and create an inversion of that group for finding invalid characters:

```
allowedCharacters = '0-9a-zA-Z\\^\\&\\\'\\@\\{\\}\\[\\]\\,\\$\\=\\!\\-\\#\\(\\)\\.\\%\\+\\~\\_ ';
allowedRegex = new RegExp('^[' + allowedCharacters + ']+$')
notAllowedRegex = new RegExp('[^' + allowedCharacters + ']', 'g')

var invalidString = 'πa√b';
allowedRegex.test(invalidString) // false

invalidString.match(notAllowedRegex); // ["π", "√"]
```

Note you have to escape all backslashes `\` in the regex string, because it's a string, not a regex literal.

This works simply by constructing a regex with `[^...]` which inverts anything inside the square brackets. For example `[^a]` will match anything that's **not** the character `a`. It uses the native RegExp class to construct a regex based on strings. The `notAllowedRegex` uses the global (`g`) flag to show all characters not matching the allowed characters.